# Sending and Verifying SSL certificate using c/c++

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I am actually working on a protocol security. I need to send the certificate and verify it on the other side.

Now here is what I have planned:
1 Send the certificate chain just like a normal stream of data
2.Capture it on the other side and store it in a char[] buffer

Now, how to verify the certificate from this char[]buffer and extract the needed parameters?

I need it in c/c++.

Comment: This is just a single question, not the whole protocol, right? What I mean is you are not going to accept that the entity sending the cert is the owner of the cert without additional proof, correct?

Comment: Is it for the TLS protocol? If you are using OpenSSL, openssl internally does it for you in it's SSL code? For what purpose do you need to implement the above?

Comment: Are you asking OpenSSL for the certificate which was used to establish an SSL connection? If so, you can trust OpenSSL to verify that the cert it gives you is owned by the party on the other side of the connection. However, if you take a stream of data and pass it to OpenSSL to decode OpenSSL will give you a certificate which you can validate. But that still tells you nothing about the identity of the sender. It is the difference between me handing you my photo ID and a stranger behind a curtain doing it. My ID is still valid in either case, but you shouldn't do business with the stranger.

Comment: I have resolved the issue nearly. Now I only need to verify the sender of the certificate with the certificate owner. Not much of an issue. Will post the answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post about [Verifying Using a Certificate Store using OpenSSL](http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2009/02/15/verifying-using-a-certificate-store/) shows how to verify certificate against CA.

Comment: I cant use openssl. I am writing my own protocol.

Comment: "I cant use openssl..." - then why did you tag the question with OpenSSL?