# Verify SSL Certificate loaded in Char[] or memory in C/C++

Tags: c++, security, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have the server certificate in a char[]. Now I also have the access to the CA certificate file.
How can I verify the certificate loaded in the char[] variable.

Please help

Comment: Duplicate of own post [Sending and Verifying SSL certificate using c/c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912921/sending-and-verifying-ssl-certificate-using-c-c)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this blog post about [Verifying Using a Certificate Store](http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2009/02/15/verifying-using-a-certificate-store/) using OpenSSL is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issues.
There are scores of functions in OpenSSL which is not documented properly. The following openssl should be used to verify the certificate when it is loaded in the memory or char[]:

```
int X509_verify(X509*, EVP_PKEY*);
```

It returns 1 if successful and 0 if verification fails.

X509* is pointer to the certificate.

```
BIO *bio;
X509 *peer_cert;
bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());  
BIO_puts(bio, (const char*)peerCert_buf);
peer_cert = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio,NULL,NULL,NULL) ;
```

peerCert_buf is a char[] containing the content of the certificate file.

EVP_PKEY* is pointer to the public key present in a certificate. You can use this to extract the public key from the CA certificate.

```
EVP_PKEY* key = X509_get_pubkey(ca);
```

ca is X509* containing the CA certificate.

Comment: "There are scores of functions in OpenSSL which is not documented properly" - yep, welcome to OpenSSL. It has got lots of other treats, too.